# Decoupling messaging and web services

Tags: web-services, rabbitmq

I'm going to be building an app shortly that requires reliable, reasonably high throughput messaging. Many of the endpoint consumers of our messages are SOAP web sevices however.

RabbitMQ and related technologies look very attractive - decoupling message delivery from the application, and providing a reliable message queuing system that can persist even through a reboot. This sounds very attractive, but from what I've read, RabbitMQ is designed for an architecture in which you maintain both the consumer and the publisher.

Are there any similar messaging systems that can target web services?

Comment: Are you wanting the messaging system to send SOAP for you?

Comment: Yes, we need to send SOAP to a number of web services. It would be great though if our apps could be message delivery agnostic however and have those concerns handed by a messaging service like Rabbit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will always need some mapping between the message and the parameters of the web service.  Should be very easy to create a small "bridge" app to receive the message and call the web service.  You would still gain teh advantages of using RabbitMQ / SOA and the arcitectures this allows